# Is there a way to compile google tests which use mocks when compiling with -Weffc++ flag on gcc

Tags: unit-testing, c++14, googletest, gcc-warning, googlemock

I am using google test as test framework, and use google mock to write mock classes. Everything works as intended!

The problem is that I would like to increase the quality of my code eliminating all the warnings in my tests and turning every warning in to errors so that they never come back.

When using **-Weffc++** in combination with **-Werror** flag to compile I get errors like:

```
Error XYZ::Mock_SonicBoom::gmock0_kammeHamme_24' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Werror=effc++]
```

***Can I do something in my code to fix this error?***

I know that using the flag **-Wno-effc++** to build my unit tests allows me to compile, but I'd rather like to fix the problem in the code if there is one, and if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the mock method you will be able to get past the error:

```
MOCK_METHOD0(kammeHamme, void()){};
```

Notice the `{}` at the end.